# Does this sentence need something else to identify the husband as the one who smashed the window?

Tags: grammar

> The woman states that her husband punched her, and he smashed her windows.

Is there something else that needs to be added to identify the husband as the one who smashed the window?

Comment: Who else does "he" refer to in that sentence? Is there anything in the context around that sentence to suggest that "he" could be anyone else? For example: "The policeman comes to the house. The woman states that her husband punched her, and he smashed her windows." Without anything else, who else can "he" refer to?

Comment: What is your idea about who else could have smashed the windows? With the words "her husband," the sentence leaves us with only one "he" to work with.

Comment: Nope. You can even remove “he” and the sentence works just fine.

Comment: "The woman states that her husband punched her and smashed her windows." The statement is perfectly clear, and all the facts are in.